# How can you join two or more dictionaries created by Bio.SeqIO.index?

Tags: biopython

I would like to be able to join the two "dictionaries" stored in "indata" and "pairdata", but this code,

```
indata = SeqIO.index(infile, infmt)
pairdata = SeqIO.index(pairfile, infmt)
indata.update(pairdata)
```

produces the following error:

```
indata.update(pairdata)
TypeError: update() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I have tried using,

```
indata = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(infile, infmt))
pairdata = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(pairfile, infmt))
indata.update(pairdata)
```

which does work, but the resulting dictionaries take up too much memory to be practical for for the sizes of infile and pairfile I have.

The final option I have explored is:

```
indata = SeqIO.index_db(indexfile, [infile, pairfile], infmt)
```

which works perfectly, but is very slow. Does anyone know how/whether I can successfully join the two indexes from the first example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeqIO.index` returns a read-only dictionary-like object, so `update` will not work on it (apologies for the confusing error message; I just checked in a fix for that to the main Biopython repository).

The best approach is to either use index_db, which will be slower but
only needs to index the file once, or to define a higher level object
which acts like a dictionary over your multiple files. Here is a
simple example:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

class MultiIndexDict:
    def __init__(self, *indexes):
        self._indexes = indexes
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for idx in self._indexes:
            try:
                return idx[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        raise KeyError("{0} not found".format(key))

indata = SeqIO.index("f001", "fasta")
pairdata = SeqIO.index("f002", "fasta")
combo = MultiIndexDict(indata, pairdata)

print combo['gi|3318709|pdb|1A91|'].description
print combo['gi|1348917|gb|G26685|G26685'].description
print combo["key_failure"]
```

Comment: I'm quite new classes and inheritance. I would like to be able to iterate over the MultiIndexDict as well, is it possible to inherit methods from SeqIO.index, e.g. the `keys()` or `iterkeys()` iterators? Can I just do `class MultiIndexDict(SeqIO.index):`?

Comment: You'd need to define a iterkeys method which returned the all the keys from all the children dictionaries etc.

Answer (score 1):

In you don't plan to use the index again and memory isn't a limitation (which both appear to be true in your case), you can tell Bio.SeqIO.index_db(...) to use an in memory SQLite3 index with the special index name ":memory:" like so:

```
indata = SeqIO.index_db(":memory:", [infile, pairfile], infmt)
```

where infile and pairfile are filenames, and infmt is their format type as defined in Bio.SeqIO (e.g. "fasta").

This is actually a general trick with Python's SQLite3 library. For a small set of files this should be much faster than building the SQLite index on disk.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and provides a solution to the more general problem I was facing. The SQLite3 database seems to take up roughly half the space of the input sequence files, whereas SeqIO.to_dict seemed to use more than 6 times the size of the sequence input files (the node I was using crashed after filling up 126GB of RAM from 20GB input). It'll be interesting to compare the memory:speed tradeoff between this solution and @Brad 's below.

Comment: Does `indata = index_db(":memory:", existing_indexfile)` read an existing SQLite3 sequence database into memory? And would it be any faster than building the database in memory from scratch using your example above?

Comment: No. If you want to load an existing SQLite3 database just give the filename of the SQLite3 database. Reloading an existing database should be MUCH faster than re-indexing. This is the normal usage - build the index once to an SQLite database (which may be slow), but then reload it in future (which is fast).